# How to draw the following FSA?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-graphdrawing

I tried to draw the following FSA to the best of my abilities, but still certain edges are not showing well (because they are not curvy) and state 1 is not aligned with the rest.

Is it possible to:

1. perhaps make the states slightly smaller
2. align 1 with 2 (so it is right above)
3. make the edges go properly for q1 -> q6, etc. instead of going over state 3 it should be curvy, for example.
4. give some space for edge 1->4 and 2->3 so I can have words for both of them.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning,decorations.text,topaths,arrows.meta,decorations.pathmorphing,quotes}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,on grid,auto] 
   \node[state] (q_0)   {$0$}; 
   \node[state] (q_1) [above right=of q_0]  {$1$}; 
   \node[state] (q_2) [right=of q_0]  {$2$}; 
   \node[state] (q_11) [below=of q_2]  {$11$}; 
   \node[state] (q_3) [above right=of q_2]  {$3$}; 
   \node[state] (q_4) [below right=of q_3]  {$4$}; 
   \node[state] (q_5) [right=of q_3]  {$5$}; 
   \node[state] (q_6) [right=of q_5]  {$6$}; 
   \node[state] (q_7) [below right=of q_5] {$7$}; 
   \node[state] (q_8) [right=of q_7]  {$8$}; 
   \node[state] (q_9) [right=of q_8]  {$9$}; 
   \node[state] (q_10) [right=of q_9]  {$10$}; 

    \path[->] 
    (q_0) edge  node [swap] {b} (q_1)
      edge  node [swap] {b} (q_2)
      edge  node [swap] {b} (q_11)
    (q_1) edge  node [swap] {b} (q_4)
      edge  node [swap] {b} (q_5)
      edge  node [swap] {b} (q_6)
    (q_2) edge  node [swap] {b} (q_3)
      edge  node [swap] {b} (q_4)
    (q_4) edge  node [swap] {b} (q_7)
    (q_6) edge  node [swap] {b} (q_8)
    (q_7) edge  node [swap] {b} (q_8)
    (q_8) edge  node [swap] {b} (q_9)
    (q_9) edge  node [swap] {b} (q_10)
    (q_11) edge  node [swap] {b} (q_4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The code wasn't previewing correctly, because you cannot go straight from an enumeration point (4. in your case) into an MWE.  So I just added a blank line, so that `MWE:` was not part of point 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `in` and `out` keys to make the edges "curvy".

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning,decorations.text,topaths,arrows.meta,decorations.pathmorphing,quotes}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,on grid,auto] 
   \node[state] (q_0)   {$0$}; 
   \node[state] (q_2) [right=of q_0]  {$2$}; 
   \node[state] (q_1) [above={sqrt(2)*1cm} of q_2]  {$1$}; 
   \node[state] (q_11) [below=of q_2]  {$11$}; 
   \node[state] (q_3) [above right=of q_2]  {$3$}; 
   \node[state] (q_4) [below right=of q_3]  {$4$}; 
   \node[state] (q_5) [right=of q_3]  {$5$}; 
   \node[state] (q_6) [right=of q_5]  {$6$}; 
   \node[state] (q_7) [below right=of q_5] {$7$}; 
   \node[state] (q_8) [right=of q_7]  {$8$}; 
   \node[state] (q_9) [right=of q_8]  {$9$}; 
   \node[state] (q_10) [right=of q_9]  {$10$}; 

    \path[->] 
    (q_0) edge  node [swap] {b} (q_1)
      edge  node [swap] {b} (q_2)
      edge  node [swap] {b} (q_11)
    (q_1) edge  node [pos=0.8] {b} (q_4)
      edge[in=135,out=45]  node [swap] {b} (q_5)
      edge[in=135,out=90]  node [swap] {b} (q_6)
    (q_2) edge  node [swap] {b} (q_3)
      edge  node [swap] {b} (q_4)
    (q_4) edge  node [swap] {b} (q_7)
    (q_6) edge  node [swap] {b} (q_8)
    (q_7) edge  node [swap] {b} (q_8)
    (q_8) edge  node [swap] {b} (q_9)
    (q_9) edge  node [swap] {b} (q_10)
    (q_11) edge  node [swap] {b} (q_4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Personally I'd move the 3 node a bit to the right.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning,decorations.text,topaths,arrows.meta,decorations.pathmorphing,quotes}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,on grid,auto] 
   \node[state] (q_0)   {$0$}; 
   \node[state] (q_2) [right=of q_0]  {$2$}; 
   \node[state] (q_1) [above={sqrt(2)*1cm} of q_2]  {$1$}; 
   \node[state] (q_11) [below=of q_2]  {$11$}; 
   \node[state] (q_3) [right=of q_1]  {$3$}; 
   \node[state] (q_4) [below right=of q_3]  {$4$}; 
   \node[state] (q_5) [right=of q_3]  {$5$}; 
   \node[state] (q_6) [right=of q_5]  {$6$}; 
   \node[state] (q_7) [below right=of q_5] {$7$}; 
   \node[state] (q_8) [right=of q_7]  {$8$}; 
   \node[state] (q_9) [right=of q_8]  {$9$}; 
   \node[state] (q_10) [right=of q_9]  {$10$}; 

    \path[->] 
    (q_0) edge  node [swap] {b} (q_1)
      edge  node [swap] {b} (q_2)
      edge  node [swap] {b} (q_11)
    (q_1) edge  node [pos=0.8] {b} (q_4)
      edge[in=135,out=45]  node [swap] {b} (q_5)
      edge[in=135,out=90]  node [swap] {b} (q_6)
    (q_2) edge  node [swap] {b} (q_3)
      edge  node [swap] {b} (q_4)
    (q_4) edge  node [swap] {b} (q_7)
    (q_6) edge  node [swap] {b} (q_8)
    (q_7) edge  node [swap] {b} (q_8)
    (q_8) edge  node [swap] {b} (q_9)
    (q_9) edge  node [swap] {b} (q_10)
    (q_11) edge  node [swap] {b} (q_4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]